# Hide spinner only for specific ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, bind

I am using a spinner using tutorial shown [here](http://techscouting.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/how-to-create-a-loading-animation-spinner-using-jquery/)

there are 3 functions running ajax calls 
I want to hide it for only a specific function running ajax call, how to do this ?

Currently my code for adding spinner for ajax call is this :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
                $(this).show();
            }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
                $(this).hide();
            }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
                $(this).hide();
      });
  });
```

its exactly what is shown in the tutorial which I've linked above.
Now how do I make it work only for 2 ajax calling functions out of 3 ?

ps : Should I unbind it and bind it everytime ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for an ajax-call that doesn't use ajaxStart/ajaxStop (which is what you're using to show/hide your spinkner i think, theres no information about that in your question) just set `global: false` like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  context: document.body,
  global: false,
  success: function(data){
    $('#test').html(data);
});
```

for more information, take a look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).